# What is the advantage of using Kendo Mobile buttons instead of handling clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, kendo-mobile

I am developing a Kendo Mobile app and want to know what is the advantages of using a Kendo Mobile button instead of handling the same event using a regular jQuery click handler?

Some elements I don't want styled like the native Kendo buttons, but still want to handle the clicks. Also if programatically adding button functionality you have to make an additional call to `$("#button").kendoMobileButton();` before handling the click.

[The documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/button) does not give very much info on why Kendo Mobile buttons are to be used, besides the automatic binding and styling when already populated in a view, which is very rare in most of my cases.

Comment: the advantage is that you have to pay after 30days

Comment: @codelio ... the actual cost of ownership are far in excess of alternative frameworks. Even though you would have to assemble a bunch of libraries, each one is going to be better than the kitchen sink effort that goes into Kendo. There's a lot of good things, but nothing is best of class, and some is just ... annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo widgets are highly touch optimized. if you create an HTML element with onclick event bound on it, and use on a touch device along with a Kendo button,(do this on a device. not on a browser or emulator) you will see the difference. 'Click' is a desktop event and Tap is the mobile event... Kendo button  provides  cross-platform compatible solution for handling user-initiated touch events which wont be available when you bind click event to normal html elements.

if you are using the Kendo framework and want HTML elements to capture taps, you can capture the [Tap event](http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/touch/index.html#/) .  You can see more [documentation here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/touch)